# Get simcard information using flutter

Tags: android, ios, dart, flutter

I want to get simcard information like (Carrier name or ISP, serial number, network operator code, country code ...etc)
I searched for any information in the flutter website and I only found this 
https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/sim_service#-example-tab-

The link explains how to do that only on android but I need this for both android and IOS.

Is there a way to do that in flutter? or I should make myself the code for android and IOS? (which will be a pain)

Comment: On iOS there's a very limited amount of data you can obtain - using CoreTelephony you can get carrier name, country code and mobile network code, but that's it. You can forget about SIM card's serial number.

Answer (score 5):

You can use this plugin named [flutter_sim_info](https://pub.dev/packages/sim_info).

You can get usim information both platform android and ios.

> A Flutter plugin for read SIM information.
> You can get SIM data for MCC, MNC, country code, etc...
>
> Note: There are similarities and differences between the data available on Android and iOS. Read the usage.